# Elasticsearch connecting to some random IP

Tags: linux, curl, elasticsearch

Whenever I am executing curl command to query my Elasticsearch Instance, I am seeing it is trying to connect to random IP 208.73.211.70

```
curl -4 -u admin:root123 localhost:9200/amas/tasks/_search?pretty -v
* About to connect() to localhost port 9200 (#0)
*   Trying 208.73.211.70...
```

I have not configured this IP anywhere in my configuration. Does anyone have idea what might be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry for localhost was missing in my /etc/hosts file. Because of which localhost was getting resolved to my domain address instead of 127.0.0.1. Adding localhost entry in /etc/hosts file resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

That's something cURL is doing. If there is no Elasticsearch instance running on 208.73.211.70 it's not even reaching Elasticsearch.

Maybe you have a weird settings in hosts or some broken DNS entries?

Comment: Entry for localhost was missing in my /etc/hosts file. Because of which localhost was getting resolved to my domain address instead of 127.0.0.1. Adding localhost entry in /etc/hosts file resolved it.